# Passenger > how do you get the LoadModule config after Passenger has installed?

Tags: apache, passenger

I installed Passenger but didn't copy the `LoadModule` config for Apache.

Now I need to paste that snippet into the Apache conf file. How can I get Passenger to output this again?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `passenger-config about ruby-command` to retrieve paths the load module needs.  `passenger-config --help` is useful to get a list of commands you can use to configure and test your set up.